# Is there a way of restricting an API's processor resource in c#?

Tags: c#, api, processor

The app I am working on calls upon an external API to process certain requests the user may make.  This is of course done in a seprate thread to try and prevent the UI from freezing or slowing down.  However, the external API produces it's own mass of threads and does some processor intensive work.  As soon as calls are made to it, the CPU usage goes up to 100%.  This then locks up my UI.  Is there any way in C# of restricting the available CPU usage to a third party API?

Comment: did you correctly separate ui and working-threads? i suppose you did not, as this is a common problem if these 2 threads are not correctly separated...

Comment: When you say external API do you mean a DLL you included inproc or does it mean an external process (out-of-proc COM, remoting or similar)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of in this scenario, is change the thread priorities. You could increase your UI thread's priority a little, or try to lower the other thread's priorities.

The latter is considered more proper, but in your case a bit tricky, as you will have to query for all running threads, find out which are the worker threads, and lower their priority. You probably need to detect new threads and alter their priority too.

Comment: Also make sure to test if the api code is monopolizing some other resource, like the disk or some key lock in the windows api.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unaware of a way to restrict an API call to a given processor resource.  There are definitely ways to curtail processor usage within an Application but not along a given API path.

I think the best solution for you here is to do the following

1. Make the API call from a child process
2. Restrict the child process execution such that it won't peg 100% of all CPUs.  The simplest way to do this is to give the process a lower priority.

   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass.aspx

Comment: Re. #2: this would be a case for running that process at a slightly lower priority: it can occupy 100% CPU but only if nothing of normal or higher priority can run.

Comment: will that prevent the API from hammering it then?  If so that sounds perfect.  Could you be so kind as to provide me with a link or an example.  Thanks

Comment: @Richard that would be my inclination as well.

Comment: @DrLazer as @Richard pointed out you can start the second process with a lower priority. This would give the UI process procedence over the child process such that it can't prevent it from running.

Comment: So if the thread making a call the the API function (which kicks off its own threads) is low priority.  Will that be inherited by any theads kicked off by the API?

Comment: The answer to that is a resounding no.  Grrr